# how to retrieve the content provider from the navigator view part

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to know how to retrieve the content provider from the navigator view part.

What i have in my custom navigator is a custom provider defined like this in my eclipse plugin:

```
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
   <navigatorContent
         contentProvider="my.navigator.MyCustomContentProvider"
         id="MyCustomContentProvider"
         name="name">             
         <triggerPoints>
 ...
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
        class="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator"
        id="my.navigator.id"
...
```

Everything works fine but when i try to obtain my custom content provider from another place in the code i don't know where to find it:

I'm trying something like this but it's not working! why?:

```
IViewPart view = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().findView( "my.navigator.id" );
if(view instanceof CommonNavigator){
   CommonNavigator nav = (CommonNavigator)view;
   IContentProvider icp = nav.getCommonViewer().getContentProvider();
   if(icp instanceof MyCustomContentProvider){
       //it never enters here!
```

This `IContentProvider` is not what i expected! why this is not the `MyCustomContentProvider`? and how to retrieve my custom content provider (`MyCustomContentProvider`)?

(note the navigator control is a `Tree` object, but from this `Tree` object i also don't know to retrieve the `TreeViewer` that holds the correct content provider...right?)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the CommonViewer the tree content provider is always `org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider`. This content provider uses the `INavigatorContentService` to access your content provider. I don't see a way to access your content provider directly.